# How does :local(.class) { } work in CSS Modules?

Tags: css, css-modules

I've started using [CSS modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules), however I cannot find any examples of how exactly this works:

```css
:local(.class){
    /* some property */
}
```

All classes are local by default, so what does `:local` or `:global` mean?

Comment: This is a good question, probably one you should ask on the github page for CSS Modules. Then maybe you can share that answer here.

Answer (score 9):

That's right, all classes are local by default. But if you switched a block to `global` and you need a local selector inside, this where you need `local` applied.

```
:global {
   .a {
    ...
  }
  :local(.b) {
    ...
  }
}
```

compiles to

```
.a {
  ...
}
.b___1bJNe {
  ...
}
```